# solution for paypal null response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal-rest-sdk

While executing the line
`var createdPayout = payout.Create(apiContext, false);` in paypal batch payout using paypal .net sdk, there are chances that we don't get any response from paypal.In such cases, how can I assure that the transaction got completed?

Can any one please help me to find a solution
Thanks in advance.